# simple convergence property proof (Sequences)

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Question: Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be convergent sequences with $a_n \Rightarrow L$ and $b_n \Rightarrow M$ as $n \Rightarrow \infty$.

Prove that $a_nb_n \Rightarrow LM$

Solution: (My Attempt). Instead of redoing it could someone just tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thx

WTS:

(1) $\exists L \in R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_1 > 0$ such that for all $n \in N_1$, if $n > N_1$, then

$|a_n - L| < \text{(We dont know yet)}$

(2) $\exists M \in R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists M > 0$, such that for all $m \in M$, if $m > M$, then

$|b_n - M| < \text{(We dont know yet)}$

Choose N = $\text{we dont know yet} > 0$

Suppose $n > N$ and $m > M$, then

$$|a_nb_n - LM| = |a_nb_n - a_nM + a_nM - LM| $$

$$= |a_n(b_n - M) + M(a_n - L)| \text{ by algebra}$$

$$\leq |a_n(b_n-M)| + |M(a_n - L)| \text{ triangle inequality}$$

$$= |a_n||b_n - M| + |M||a_n - L|$$

Can we say $|a_n||b_n - M| = \epsilon/2$ same with $|M||a_n - L| = \epsilon/2$ ? Then Q.E.D? With N = $max(N_1, M)$ ?

I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you messed up the notations were you assumed $b_{n}$ converges to M and in the proof you for all $m > M$ .

So I am redoing the same proof

I am assuming both the sequences are real

In order to prove the given statement it is helpful to note that every real convergent sequence is a cauchy sequence and hence a bounded sequence.

Let $\{a_{n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers converging to $a$ and $\{b_{n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers converging to $b$.

$|a_{n}b_{n} - ab| = |a_{n}b_{n} - a_{n}b+a_{n}b-ab|= |a_{n}(b_{n}-b)+b(a_{n}-a)|$

therefore

$|a_{n}b_{n} - ab|\leq |a_{n}||b_{n}-b|+|b||a_{n}-a|$  for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

As noted above $a_{n}$ is a bounded sequence, so there exists a real number $\alpha$ greater than zero such that $|a_{n}| \leq \alpha$ for all n.

Therefore

$|a_{n}b_{n} - ab|\leq \alpha |b_{n}-b|+|b||a_{n}-a|$  for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

now choose $\epsilon_{1}=\frac{\epsilon}{\alpha}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and if $b \neq 0$ then choose $\epsilon_{2}=\frac{\epsilon}{|b|}$.

So for $\epsilon_{1}$ there exists a $N_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

for all $n\geq N_{1}$ $|b_{n}-b|<\epsilon_{1}$ -------(*)

So for $\epsilon_{2}$ there exists a $N_{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

for all $n\geq N_{2}$ $|a_{n}-a|<\epsilon_{2}$ -------(**)

Let N = max{$N_{1},N_{2}$}

then by (*) and (**)

$|a_{n}b_{n} - ab|\leq \alpha |b_{n}-b|+|b||a_{n}-a| < \alpha \epsilon_{1}+|b|\epsilon_{2} $ for all $n\geq N$.

$|a_{n}b_{n} - ab| < 2\epsilon $ for all $n\geq N$.

Thus $a_{n}b_{n}$ converges to $ab$.

Comment: Anyway to do it like this: "$|a_n||b_n - M| = \epsilon/2$ same with $|M||a_n - L| = \epsilon/2"$?. Its how my teacher does it, wonder if I can duplicate.

Comment: sorry in the end I messed it up, now I edited it and If we take  $\epsilon_{1}=\frac{\epsilon}{2\alpha}$ $\epsilon_{2}=\frac{\epsilon}{2|b|}$  then we get  $|a_n||b_n - b| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|b||a_n - a| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Comment: oh okay thx. I get it

Answer (score 0):

You know that there exists $\overline{N_1}$ such that for every $n>\overline {N_1}$ you have $|L|-1 \leq |a_n| \leq |L|+1$, and similarly there exists $\overline{N_2}$ such that for every $n> \overline {N_2}$ you have $|M|-1 \leq |b_n| \leq |M|+1$.

Then the terms $|a_n|$ and $|b_n|$ are bounded and you just have to pick an  $\epsilon>0$ according to them.